# sympy: How to solve this system of transcendental equations?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve a system of transcendental equations using sympy:

```
from sympy import *
A, Z, phi, d, a, tau, t, R, u, v = symbols('A Z phi d a tau t R u v', real=True)

system = [
    Eq(A, sqrt(R**2*cos(u)**2 + 2*R*d*cos(a)*cos(u) + d**2 + 2*d*(v*sin(tau) - (R*sin(u) + t)*cos(tau))*sin(a) + (v*sin(tau) - (R*sin(u) + t)*cos(tau))**2)),
    Eq(Z, v*cos(tau) + (R*sin(u) + t)*sin(tau)),
    Eq(phi, (R*sin(a)*cos(u) - (v*sin(tau) - (R*sin(u) + t)*cos(tau))*cos(a))/A),
]
```

or in euclidian coordinates:

```
system = [
     Eq(A, sqrt(d**2 + 2*d*x*cos(a) + 2*d*(z*sin(tau) - (t + y)*cos(tau))*sin(a) + x**2 + (z*sin(tau) - (t + y)*cos(tau))**2)),
     Eq(Z, z*cos(tau) + (t + y)*sin(tau)),
     Eq(phi, (x*sin(a) - (z*sin(tau) - (t + y)*cos(tau))*cos(a))/A),
     Eq(R**2, x**2+y**2),
]
```

Essentially this is an intersection of a circle (radius A) with a skewed (angle τ) cylinder (radius R) rotating (angle a) around an eccentric axis (d). I'm interested in the function φ(A, Z) as I need to evaluate it for several hundred combinations of A and Z for a few combinations of the other parameters (R, A, d, t, τ).

Here is what I tried:

- Directly using `solve(system, [u, v, phi])`: Needs too much time to complete.
- Reducing it to one equation using first and then using `solveset()`.
- Inserting numbers for all parameters (example: `R, A, d, t, tao = 25, 150, 125, 2, 5/180*pi`) then using any combination of the `N()` and `solve()` or `solveset()`.
- I was able to get solutions for the simplified problem of the unskewed cylinder (`t, tao = 0, 0`) with `d = sqrt(A**2 - R**2)`.

**How can I solve this system of equations? Failing that: How can I get numeric values for φ for a few dozen combinations of the parameters and a few hundred points (A, Z) each?**

---

If you are interested. Here is the code leading up to the equation:

```
A, Z, phi, d, a, tau, t, R, u, v = symbols('A Z phi d a tau t R u v', real=True)

r10, z10, phi10 = symbols('r10 z10 phi_10', real=True)
system10 = [Eq(A, r10), Eq(Z, z10), Eq(phi, phi10)]

x9, x8, y8, z8 = symbols('x9 x8 y8 z8', real=True)
system8 = [e.subs(r10, sqrt(x9**2+y8**2)).subs(z10, z8).subs(phi10, y8/A).subs(x9, x8+d) for e in system10]

r6, phi7, phi6, z6 = symbols('r6 phi_7 phi_6 z6', real=True)
system6 = [e.subs(x8, r6*cos(phi7)).subs(y8, r6*sin(phi7)).subs(z8, z6).subs(phi7, phi6+a) for e in system8]

x6, y6 = symbols('x_6 y_6', real=True)
system6xy = [simplify(expand_trig(e).subs(cos(phi6), x6/r6).subs(sin(phi6), y6/r6)) for e in system6]

# solve([simplify(e.subs(phi6, u).subs(r6, R).subs(z6, v).subs(d, sqrt(A**2-R**2))) for e in system6], [u, v, phi]) -> phi = acos(+-R/A)

r5, phi5, x5 = symbols('r_5 phi_5 x_5', real=True)
system5 = [e.subs(x6, x5).subs(y6, r5*cos(phi5)).subs(z6, r5*sin(phi5)) for e in system6xy]

r4, phi4, x4 = symbols('r_4 phi_4 x_4', real=True)
system4 = [e.subs(phi5, phi4 + tau).subs(r5, r4).subs(x5, x4) for e in system5]

x3, y3, z3 = symbols('x_3 y_3 z_3', real=True)
system3 = [expand_trig(e).subs(cos(phi4), y3/r4).subs(sin(phi4), z3/r4).subs(r4, sqrt(y3**2+z3**2)).subs(x4, x3) for e in system4]

x2, y2, z2 = symbols('x_2 y_2 z_2', real=True)
system2 = [e.subs(x3, x2).subs(y3, y2+t).subs(z3, z2) for e in system3]

system = [simplify(e.subs(x2, R*cos(u)).subs(y2, R*sin(u)).subs(z2, v)) for e in system2]

# solve([simplify(e.subs(tau, 0).subs(t, 0).subs(d, sqrt(A**2-R**2))) for e in system], [u, v, phi]) -> phi = acos(+-R/A)
```

Comment: The question is "How can I get numeric values"  but you use SymPy, a library for __symbolic__ computations? Looks like a wrong tool for the job. I would begin with [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) in SciPy, and if the results are unsatisfactory, try the various options in its `root`  method.

Comment: I would prefer a symbolic solution for this problem. If this is not possible (and it seems it's not) I'm also happy to have a solution that solves my immediate goals (as described above).

Answer (score 0):

Your first two equations must be solved for u and v; the 3rd then gives the corresponding value of phi. You can easily solve the 2nd for v.

Approach:

Solve the 2nd equation for v and substitute that into the 1st to obtain a function of only u and other variables, **the values of which you will define** (solving this high order symbolic expression will not be effective). You can't easily solve that equation for u, but you can get a reasonable solution for sin(u) in terms of cos(u) to give two roots: sin(u) = f1(cos(u)) and f2(cos(u)). I get

```
(Z*sin(tau) + d*sin(a)*cos(tau) - t - sqrt(A**2 - R**2*cos(u)**2 -
2*R*d*cos(a)*cos(u) - d**2*cos(a)**2)*cos(tau))/R
```

and

```
(Z*sin(tau) + d*sin(a)*cos(tau) - t + sqrt(A**2 - R**2*cos(u)**2 -
2*R*d*cos(a)*cos(u) - d**2*cos(a)**2)*cos(tau))/R
```

If we let x = cos(u) we know that `f1(x)**2 + x**2 - 1 = 0` (which we call z1(x) and similarly z2(x) for the other root) AND we know that x is constrained to the range of [-1, 1]. So we can bisect zi(x) for x in the range of [-1, 1] to find the value of x; u = asin(x) can be substituted into the second equation to find v; finally, u and v can be substituted into the 3rd to find phi.

e.g. for {tau: 3, R: 7, A: 7, t: 4, a: 3, Z: 3, d: 2}
I get x = sin(u) = {-.704, 0.9886} which gives v = {-1.47, -3.16} and phi = {1.52, -.093}

Of course, those values may be meaningless if the input is meaningless, but with the right values hopefully this approach might prove worthwhile.

/c